# Is there any work around in php to read SMS content

Tags: php, sms, integration

Is there any work around in php to read SMS content which are sent on a mobile no. or lets say an organization toll free no. or any number.

Actually i need offline verification through SMS.

Customer message sent on a no. And i Need to check the authenticity of customer based on information provided in SMS.

Comment: You can receive SMS from something like [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/), which has APIs for all of the common languages, including PHP, Android, and iOS.

Comment: Are you using a GSM Modem or Server ?

Comment: Yes thats right using Twilio i can send and receive SMS. I need to keep track of  all messages sent on a particular mobile/toll free no. That might be a twilio number or a non twilio one.